# Fixed page header overlaps in-page anchors

Tags: html, url, anchor

If I have a non-scrolling header in an HTML page, fixed to the top, having a defined height:

Is there a way to use the URL anchor (the `#fragment` part) to have the browser scroll to a certain point in the page, but still respect the height of the fixed element **without the help of JavaScript**?

```
http://example.com/#bar
```

```
WRONG (but the common behavior):         CORRECT:
+---------------------------------+      +---------------------------------+
| BAR///////////////////// header |      | //////////////////////// header |
+---------------------------------+      +---------------------------------+
| Here is the rest of the Text    |      | BAR                             |
| ...                             |      |                                 |
| ...                             |      | Here is the rest of the Text    |
| ...                             |      | ...                             |
+---------------------------------+      +---------------------------------+
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10732690/offsetting-an-html-anchor-to-adjust-for-fixed-header

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/hash-tag-links-padding/

Comment: @ax YES, that's the best answer. Also check http://nicolasgallagher.com/jump-links-and-viewport-positioning/demo/ inside it. This worked best for me: `.dislocate50px, #bar {
          padding: 50px 0 0;
          margin: -50px 0 0;
          -webkit-background-clip: content-box;
          background-clip: content-box;
      }`

Comment: i'm seeking a solution which 
* works for anchors coming in from same page or other page, 
* and which adjusts page-down key-press so that content doesn't get clipped by header, 
* and which allows sib-div footer to scroll up with content-div. Haven't found a solution yet! But i must say, i think the right way would target the whole content div, and not each individual anchor. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51070758/css-to-make-vertical-scrolling-region-under-fixed-header

Comment: @ax. CSS-tricks.com has a much better newer article about `scroll-padding-top` here: https://css-tricks.com/fixed-headers-on-page-links-and-overlapping-content-oh-my/ Corresponding answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56467997/247696

Comment: I also used https://css-tricks.com/hash-tag-links-padding The only issue I'm having is that anchor references on the same page are inserting whitespace above the H3 realtime on the page(?)

Answer (score 180, accepted):

I had the same problem.
I solved it by adding a class to the anchor element with the topbar height as the padding-top value.

```
<h1><a class="anchor" name="barlink">Bar</a></h1>
```

I used this CSS:

```
.anchor { padding-top: 90px; }
```

Comment: @Tomalak Be aware that this solution makes links inside the padding area non-clickable. To fix this you must use z-index, and set the links value higher than the anchor's. Remember you topbar should have the highest z-index value, so the page's content don't float ontop of the topbar when you scroll.

Comment: Did not work in Chrome v28 due to a WebKit [fixed position bug](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11258877/fixed-element-disappears-in-chrome) causing header to disappear. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14569741/920511) did the trick im my case.

Comment: MuttenXd.. you are my hero.  I had weird non-function link problem on my site (unrelated to anchors) been driving me crazy. Your non-clickable comment really helped. I owe ya big!

Comment: Isn't adding padding to the top of the anchor going to push it farther down? Don't you want it farther up instead in order to account for the fixed header?

Comment: use `<span>` instead of `<a>` to avoid the colored headlines.

Comment: As suggested in Roy Shoa's answer, add `margin-top: -90px;` to counter the gap created by padding.

Comment: I used `.anchor:target {padding-top: 90px;}` so that it only added the padding when they used the anchor tag. This way there isn't always a bunch of padding if the page loads at the top. Only when it loads a that specific point lower on the page.

Comment: <pre><code>    // handle hashes when page loads
    // <http://stackoverflow.com/a/29853395>
    function adjustAnchor() {
      const $anchor = $(':target');
      const fixedElementHeight = $('.navbar-fixed-top').outerHeight();
      if ($anchor.length > 0)
        window.scrollTo(0, $anchor.offset().top - fixedElementHeight);
    }
    $(window).on('hashchange load', adjustAnchor);
    $('body').on('click', "a[href^='#']", function (ev) {
      if (window.location.hash === $(this).attr('href')) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        adjustAnchor();
      }
    });</pre></code>

Comment: I used a little javascript to add and remove padding as needed. `$(function(){
 $('#jump').click(function() {
  $('#id').addClass("anchor");
 });
 $('.top').click(function() {
  $('#id').removeClass("anchor");
 });
});`

Comment: Note that in nowadays there is single no-hack fully cross-browser solution – `scroll-margin` / `scroll-padding`.

Comment: @mutttenxd, I followed the solution which unfortunately didn't help me. Here is the page https://dev-packed-with-purpose.pantheonsite.io/gift-concierge-new/ I'm trying to apply the solution on `Complete Form` cta button. Kindly have a look at the page and suggest some solution.

Answer (score 359):

If you can’t or don’t want to set a new class, add a fixed-height [`::before`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before) pseudo-element to the [`:target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:target) pseudo-class in CSS:

```css
:target::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 60px; /* fixed header height*/
  margin: -60px 0 0; /* negative fixed header height */
}
```

Or scroll the page relative to `:target` with jQuery:

```js
var offset = $(':target').offset();
var scrollto = offset.top - 60; // minus fixed header height
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop:scrollto}, 0);
```

Comment: This is the solution that worked perfectly for me without stuffing up anything else in my page layout.

Comment: If you use anchor.js library, the css solution works perfectly.

Comment: CSS solution has a problem when used with list in WebKit. Look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39547773/why-alignment-mark-list-is-different-on-webkit-when-using-before-height

Comment: It won't work if the target has top padding or border since it relies on margin-collapse.

Comment: Brilliant, Worked like a charm! thank you @Adripants , solved very old bug in using psuedo css without changing single dom element.

Comment: Only FYI: If the targeted anchor element has style `display: table;` then it will not work.

Comment: This is perfect—it worked without having to go back and add a class to the target ids. So simple and clean, thanks!

Comment: Note: This only worked with my code once I added `visibility: hidden;` to the `:target::before` pseudo-element.

Comment: The `:target::before` didn't work for us so I used `h1[id]::before, h2[id]::before, ..., h6[id]::before` instead (I needed to use it at headings only).

Comment: This is not working when the target is within a flexbox for me.

Comment: Thank you very much, your CSS version was the only feasible solution for me, as I didn't want to use javascript and many other css solutions required changing the anchors which I wasn't able to, as they are generated by my CMS.

Comment: For me this created a 60px-high <a> tag that was masking other links that stopped working as a result. Try this instead: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13184714/2771889

Comment: @thisismydesign, The answer you're pointing to has the same issue that you're claiming it solves.

Comment: I was using this solution for about a year and then it stopped working (Chrome 89, Edge) although it still works in Firefox.. The scroll-padding-top solution (below) does seem to work for Chrome, though.

Comment: The `:target` solution does not work if the element is using display flex.

Comment: You might need to add also `z-index: -1` or something similar to `:target`in case the slution is overlapping something it should not.

Comment: ok, after reading all the other answers and concidering, that we have now 2021, I made it work perfectly with `:target { scroll-margin-top: 60px; }` (kind of the best from both worlds)

Comment: Unfortunately this prevents clicking on elements that are above (before) the target element as they are overlapped by the pseudo-element. People should use `scroll-padding-top` unless they need IE11

Comment: This is a better answer.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10732690/offsetting-an-html-anchor-to-adjust-for-fixed-header.
For anchor on the middle of content,When there is no content below and window can not be scroll, The :target::before will suddenly add some empty block.

Comment: Does not work in my case (using Bootstrap 4.5 row with an anchor)

Answer (score 275):

```
html {
  scroll-padding-top: 70px; /* height of sticky header */
}
```

from: https://css-tricks.com/fixed-headers-on-page-links-and-overlapping-content-oh-my/

Comment: Browser support: https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-css_properties_scroll-padding-top

Comment: Works for me. I am navigating to the anchor from another page. Others didn't work. Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't work for scrolling entire page in Edge and Safari (https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=179379).

Comment: Savior! Simple,on point. None of the other solutions worked for me because I am using display:flex. Thanks a ton, it was so frustrating trying all the solutions.

Comment: This is a BEAUTIFUL solution, I used scroll-behavior: smooth !important; also to go anchor, really simple in two lines of code

Comment: Other solution I was using seemed to have stopped working in Chrome 89/Edge/IE. This solution fixed it.

Comment: This was released in Safari 14.1 as well on 4/2021.

Comment: scroll-margin-top is also an option, though I haven't figured out under what conditions, if any, it would be preferable to scroll-padding-top.

Comment: Works for me for all browsers except IE11. At least, now I can once again click on the links that are above/before this element.

Comment: This should be the top answer!

Answer (score 130):

I use this approach:

```
/* add class="jumptarget" to all targets. */

.jumptarget::before {
  content:"";
  display:block;
  height:50px; /* fixed header height*/
  margin:-50px 0 0; /* negative fixed header height */
}
```

It adds an invisible element before each target. It works IE8+.

Here are more solutions:
http://nicolasgallagher.com/jump-links-and-viewport-positioning/

Comment: look at the link Badabam provided, there is a second solution, which I use and which works in Chrome and Firefox

Comment: Tested this on the latest Firefox (55.0.3 on PC) and it works now. :-)

Answer (score 116):

From 4/2021 there is single non-hacky and fully cross-browser solution:

```css
h1 {
  scroll-margin-top: 50px
}
```

It is part of [CSS Scroll Snap spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-scroll-snap-1/). Runs on [all modern browsers](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_scroll-margin). (For more context, see the MDN pages about [`scroll-margin-top`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-margin-top), [`scroll-padding-top`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-padding-top))

Comment: What is the difference between `scroll-padding-top` and `scroll-margin-top`?

Comment: In Safari it is called `scroll-snap-margin-top`: https://caniuse.com/#search=scroll-margin-top

Comment: This one works for me, but not in Firefox for Linux version 78.

Comment: It is fixed in Safari TP now.

Comment: Released in 14.1 so it is fully cross-browser now!

Comment: I'd recommend using selector `:target` instead of given element names.

Comment: @MikkoRantalainen what's the relation with the current answer?

@Flimm it seems that using `scroll-padding-top` is preferrable in most cases. `scroll-margin-top` allows for more flexibility in some scenarii only.

Comment: If you have fixed or sticky page header, using `:target` selector fixes all fragment anchor usage instead of only selected elements (and leaving other targets incorrect). Using `:target` instead of `*` as the selector avoids applying this property to every element in the DOM.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I get what i intend by adding className tailwind `scroll-mt-32` into h2,h3... in my Next.js Tailwindcss project

Answer (score 51):

**Official Bootstrap Adopted Answer:**

```
*[id]:before { 
  display: block; 
  content: " "; 
  margin-top: -75px; // Set the Appropriate Height
  height: 75px; // Set the Appropriate Height
  visibility: hidden; 
}
```

[Credits](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/1768#issuecomment-46519033)

[Merge](https://github.com/copyleft-org/copyleft-guide/commit/476a42bf0d737e13a561dbaf6f4e1e91a333e80d)

Comment: This solution has a problem when used with list in WebKit. Look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39547773/why-alignment-mark-list-is-different-on-webkit-when-using-before-height

Comment: Note that this won't work if the target element itself happens to have `display: flex;` or `padding-top`. Do use a dedicated anchor element (like `<a name="my_link">{leave this empty}</a>`) in those cases.

Comment: It prevents clicks on links/elements that are above/before the target element. It may have been the least of two evils earlier, but nowadays people should only use `scroll-padding-top`.

Answer (score 35):

The best way that I found to handle this issue is (replace 65px with your fixed element height):

```
div:target {
  padding-top: 65px; 
  margin-top: -65px;
}
```

If you do not like to use the [target](http://css-tricks.com/on-target/) selector you can also do it in this way:

```
.my-target {
    padding-top: 65px;
    margin-top: -65px;
}
```

Note: this example will not work if the target element have a backgound color that differant from his parent.
for example:

```
<div style="background-color:red;height:100px;"></div>
<div class="my-target" style="background-color:green;height:100px;"></div>
```

in this case the green color of my-target element will overwrite his parent red element in 65px.
I did not find any pure CSS solution to handle this issue but if you do not have another background color this solution is the best.

Answer (score 20):

While some of the proposed solutions work for fragment links (= hash links) **within** the same page (like a menu link that scrolls down), I found that none of them worked in current Chrome when you want to use fragment links coming in **from other pages**.

So calling www.mydomain.com/page.html#foo from scratch will **NOT** offset your target in current Chrome with any of the given CSS solutions or JS solutions.

There is also a [jQuery bug report](https://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/14135) describing some details of the problem.

**SOLUTION**

The only option I found so far that really works in Chrome is JavaScript that is not called onDomReady but with a delay.

```
// set timeout onDomReady
$(function() {
    setTimeout(delayedFragmentTargetOffset, 500);
});

// add scroll offset to fragment target (if there is one)
function delayedFragmentTargetOffset(){
    var offset = $(':target').offset();
    if(offset){
        var scrollto = offset.top - 95; // minus fixed header height
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:scrollto}, 0);
    }
}
```

**SUMMARY**

Without a JS delay solutions will probably work in Firefox, IE, Safari, but not in Chrome.

Comment: I have come to the same conclusion and solution. It seems like every body else is forgetting about external links that use the hashtags.

Comment: I have that problem today and I've used your solution. Although it seems that you don't need timeout. This works as IIFE as well.

Comment: @kwiat1990: Yes, that may be possible – but only if your JS is placed at the very end of the HTML code. Otherwise your scroll target might not yet be in the DOM. Actually that is the whole point of using onDomReady. So I guess the timeout version is the stable way to go.

Comment: This answer was the only one that worked for external links. However it does not work for me when the link is called in the same page :( Any ideas?

Comment: @Augusto did you find a solution? I am having the same problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, no :(

Comment: Finally - I was using external anchors and none of the other solutions were working and I couldn't figure out why when everyone else was saying they were working. I did notice with this that my experience with IE was that it required twice the amount of delay to work. Perhaps a more solid method would be to put a small delay and then run a loop that checks if the element exists and when it does execute the code; perhaps with minor delays between each check.

Answer (score 14):

You can now use [scroll-margin-top](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-margin-top), which is [pretty widely adopted](https://caniuse.com/#search=scroll-margin-top).

Simply add the following CSS to the element you want to scroll to:

```
.element {
  scroll-margin-top: 2em;
}
```

Comment: `scroll-margin-top` has been suggested [earlier in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55683966/18771)

Comment: Scroll margin is not applied for scrolls to fragment target...this will not work for anchor tags https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-margin-top

Comment: Works perfectly. I have a large table and span#anchors on some cells. Have set `td span[id] { scroll-margin-top: 80px; }` and it works, scrolling exactly with this offset. Much faster rendering than pseudo-elements with margin and padding.

Comment: It did not work in Safari for a long time, but it is fixed in TP now. See https://github.com/mdn/browser-compat-data/issues/4945#issuecomment-748449872

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, works in all but IE

Comment: that's my persona favorite: `:target { scroll-margin-top: 2em; }`

Answer (score 8):

I've got it working easily with CSS and HTML, using the "anchor:before" method mentioned above. I think it works the best, because it doesn't create massive padding between your divs.

```
.anchor:before {
  content:"";
  display:block;
  height:60px; /* fixed header height*/
  margin:-60px 0 0; /* negative fixed header height */
}
```

It doesn't seem to work for the first div on the page, but you can counter that by adding padding to that first div.

```
#anchor-one{padding-top: 60px;}
```

Here's a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FRpHE/24/

Answer (score 8):

For Chrome/Safari/Firefox you could add a `display: block` and use a negative margin to compensate the offset, like:

```
a[name] {
    display: block;
    padding-top: 90px;
    margin-top: -90px;
}
```

See example http://codepen.io/swed/pen/RrZBJo

Answer (score 8):

I didn't see the option to simply use **:target** listed as an option. I've found that

`:target { margin-top: -100px; padding-top: 100px; }`

appears to work in the provided scenario. **:target** is also compatible with all modern browsers. https://caniuse.com/?search=%3Atarget

Comment: Very elegant; no messing with the layout. Works for me! I would still add JS to update the height value dynamically.

Comment: Very useful, but in some cases it can lead to the content *below* to overwrite the addressed element (if the element has a fixed height) ☹

Answer (score 7):

Just discovered another pure CSS solution that worked like a charme for me!

```
html {
  scroll-padding-top: 80px; /* height of your sticky header */
}
```

Found on [this site](https://css-tricks.com/fixed-headers-on-page-links-and-overlapping-content-oh-my/)!

Comment: A few others have discovered this solution before you, see the the answers on page 1, for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/56467997/18771

Comment: This doesn't work for scrolling entire page in Edge and Safari (https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=179379).

Answer (score 6):

You could try this:

```
<style>
h1:target { padding-top: 50px; }
</style>

<a href="#bar">Go to bar</a>

<h1 id="bar">Bar</h1>
```

Set the top padding value to the actual height of your header. This will introduce a slight extra gap at the top of your header, but it will only be visible when the user jumps to the anchor and then scrolls up. I've made up that solution for my site right now, but it only shows a small fixed bar at the top of the page, nothing too high.

Comment: Mh. Not bad, but still quite a hack (and does not work in IE, sadly).

Answer (score 6):

You can do this with jQuery:

```
var offset = $('.target').offset();
var scrollto = offset.top - 50; // fixed_top_bar_height = 50px
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop:scrollto}, 0);
```

Comment: Not ".target", should be ":target"

Comment: @MertS.Kaplan ".target" is the class 'target'.

Answer (score 6):

I wasn't having any luck with the answer listed above and ended up using this solution which worked perfectly...

Create a blank span where you want to set your anchor.

```
<span class="anchor" id="section1"></span>
<div class="section"></div>
```

And apply the following class:

```
.anchor {
  display: block;
  height: 115px;       /* same height as header */
  margin-top: -115px;  /* same height as header */
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

This solution will work even if the sections have different colored backgrounds! I found the solution at [this link.](https://pixelflips.com/blog/anchor-links-with-a-fixed-header)

Comment: Isn't that exactly the same method that [Guillaume Le Mière](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49826477/18771) and a few others have shown in this thread?

Comment: It is very similar but I think it is easier to understand and a more detailed response with an even more in-depth link to an outside source.

Comment: It is the same solution, but I can understand and follow this one easily. The others didn't give me enough information.

Answer (score 5):

It works for me:

HTML LINK to Anchor:

```
<a href="#security">SECURITY</a>
```

HTML Anchor:

```
<a name="security" class="anchor"></a>
```

CSS :

```
.anchor::before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    margin-top: -50px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I had a lot of trouble with many of the answers here and elsewhere as my bookmarked anchors were section headers in an FAQ page, so offsetting the header didn't help as the rest of the content would just stay where it was. So I thought I'd post.

What I ended up doing was a composite of a few solutions:

1. The CSS:

   ```
   .bookmark {
       margin-top:-120px;
       padding-bottom:120px; 
       display:block;
   }
   ```

Where "120px" is your fixed header height (maybe plus some margin).

2. The bookmark link HTML:

   ```
   <a href="#01">What is your FAQ question again?</a>
   ```
3. The bookmarked content HTML:

   ```
   <span class="bookmark" id="01"></span>
   <h3>What is your FAQ question again?</h3>
   <p>Some FAQ text, followed by ...</p>
   <p>... some more FAQ text, etc ...</p>
   ```

The good thing about this solution is that the `span` element is not only hidden, it is essentially collapsed and doesn't pad out your content.

I can't take much credit for this solution as it comes from a swag of different resources, but it worked best for me in my situation.

You can see the actual result [here](https://protege.com.au/skylibfaq).

Comment: Thank you very much for sharing! Old as the thread is, there still does not seem to be one canonical solution to this problem.

Comment: +SteveCinq You read my mind -- I was facing the same issues where shared solutions were not working as predicted. Adding in the `<span>` with the anchor in the span, along with adding in the padding and margin worked for me. Thanks so much for taking the time to submit this answer despite the age of the thread!

Comment: I was going to add something similar after trying SO many different techniques, I ended up having the same idea. After the start of any div that should be the anchor, I just include a span element with an anchor class and the id for it. I actually used these properties:     content: " ";
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 100px;
    margin-top: -100px;
    visibility: hidden;
    pointer-events: none;

Answer (score 5):

I solve my issue with scroll-margin-top property for the anchor element

```
scroll-margin-top: 100px;
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-margin-top

Comment: There are multiple highly upvoted answers (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55683966/266309)) mentioning this solution already. Please check existing answers before adding new ones.

Answer (score 4):

It feels somewhat hacky to my purist mind but as a css-only solution you can add padding to the active anchored element using the `:target` selector:

```css
html, body {height:100%; min-height:100%; margin:0;}
body {min-height:200%;}
header {display:inline-block; position:fixed; font-size:1.5em; height:100px; top:0; left:0; right:0; line-height:100px; background:black; text-align:center;}
header a {color:#fff;}
section {padding:30px; margin:20px;}
section:first-of-type, section:target {padding-top:130px;}
```

```html
<header><a href="#one">#One</a> <a href="#two">#two</a> <a href="#three">#three</a></header>
<section id="one"><h1>One</h1>Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Integer posuere erat a ante venenatis dapibus posuere velit aliquet.</section>
<section id="two"><h1>Two</h1>Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Integer posuere erat a ante venenatis dapibus posuere velit aliquet.</section>
<section id="three"><h1>Three</h1>Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Integer posuere erat a ante venenatis dapibus posuere velit aliquet.</section>
```

Comment: this just creates a huge space of padding above the the targeted section which you easily notice when scrolling back up. very hacky solution

Answer (score 4):

I'm using @Jpsy's answer, but for performance reasons I'm only setting the timer if the hash is present in the URL.

```
$(function() {
      // Only set the timer if you have a hash
      if(window.location.hash) {
        setTimeout(delayedFragmentTargetOffset, 500);
      }
  });

function delayedFragmentTargetOffset(){
      var offset = $(':target').offset();
      if(offset){
          var scrollto = offset.top - 80; // minus fixed header height
          $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:scrollto}, 0);
          $(':target').highlight();
      }
  };
```

Comment: OP asked not to use javascript.

Comment: Works with external links but not with in-page links.

Answer (score 3):

I found I had to use **both** *MutttenXd*'s and *Badabam*'s CSS solutions together, as the first did not work in Chrome and the second did not work in Firefox:

```
a.anchor { 
  padding-top: 90px;
}

a.anchor:before { 
  display: block;
  content: "";
  height: 90px;
  margin-top: -90px;
}

<a class="anchor" name="shipping"></a><h2>Shipping (United States)</h2>
...
```

Answer (score 3):

The way that I find being the cleanest is the following one :

```
  #bar::before {
    display: block;
    content: " ";
    margin-top: -150px;
    height: 150px;
    visibility: hidden;
    pointer-events: none;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

A minimally intrusive approach using jQuery:

Link:

```
<a href="#my-anchor-1" class="anchor-link">Go To Anchor 1</a>
```

Content:

```
<h3 id="my-anchor-1">Here is Anchor 1</a>
```

Script:

```
$(".anchor-link").click(function() {
    var headerHeight = 120;
    $('html, body').stop(true, true).animate({
        scrollTop: $(this.hash).offset().top - headerHeight
    }, 750);
    return false;
});
```

By assigning the anchor-link class to the links, the behaviour of other links (like accordion or tab controls) are not affected.

The question doesn't want javascript but [the other more popular question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10732690) is closed because of this one and I couldn't answer there.

Answer (score 2):

I needed something that works for inbound links, links on page, AND that can be targeted by JS so the page can respond to changes in the header height

HTML

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#ft_who">Who?</a></li>
  <li><a href="#ft_what">What?</a></li>
  <li><a href="#ft_when">When?</a></li>
</ul>
...
<h2 id="ft_who" class="fragment-target">Who?</h2> 
...
<a href="#">Can I be clicked?</a>
<h2 id="ft_what" class="fragment-target">What?</h2>
...
<h2 id="ft_when" class="fragment-target">When?</h2>
```

CSS

```
.fragment-target {
    display: block;
    margin-top: -HEADER_HEIGHTpx;
    padding-top: HEADER_HEIGHTpx;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

The `z-index: -1` allows links in the 'padding area' above a fragment-target to still be clickable, as commented by @MuttenXd on his answer

I haven't found an issue yet in IE 11, Edge 15+, Chrome 38+, FF 52+, or Safari 9.1+

Answer (score 1):

```
<div style="position:relative; top:-45px;">
    <a name="fragment"> </a>
</div>
```

This code should do the trick. Swap out 45px for the height of your header bar.

EDIT: If using jQuery is an option, I've also been successful using jQuery.localScroll with an offset value set. The offset option is a part of jQuery.scrollTo, which jQuery.localScroll is built upon. A demo is available here: http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/ (second window, under 'offset')

Comment: this solution works indeed, but it is not bulletproof and it requires lot of finetuning for different browsers :( good try thoug. I am searching for a solution without extra markup.

Comment: Shame this is so messy, means you can't just use IDs. Would love to find a solution, I have tried all sorts of things.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a complete jquery solution that will work in IE:

Suppose the navigation bar elements are something like this:

```
<ul>
    <li><a class="navigation" href="/#contact-us">Contact us</a></li>
    <li><a class="navigation" href="/#about-us">About us</a></li>
</ul>
```

You can use the following jquery snippet to offset the scroll:

```
$(function() {
    $("a.navigation").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        offSetScroll($(this));
    });
    offSetScrollFromLocation(window.location.href.toLowerCase());
});

function offSetScroll(anchor) {
    var href = anchor.attr("href");
    offSetScrollFromLocation(href);
}

function offSetScrollFromLocation(href) {
    //Change this according to the height of the navigation bar
    var fromTop = 250;
    if(href.indexOf("#")<=0)
        return;
    var hash=href.substring(href.indexOf("#"));
    var targetOffset = $(hash).offset().top-fromTop;
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: targetOffset}, 400, function(e) {

    });
}
```

Comment: I was able to use a slightly modified version of this code from Thunder. I tried many of the CSS-only and simpler solutions on this page and on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10732690/offsetting-an-html-anchor-to-adjust-for-fixed-header and on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10732690/offsetting-an-html-anchor-to-adjust-for-fixed-header but they were not usable due to my requirements. The page is an FAQ page with many anchors to position to, both from on and off the page, so could have have lots of blank spots. Continued in next comment ....

Comment: To make it work for me, here are the minor changes: (1) change "<=" in the href.index line to "<" to allow on-page navigation; (2) change "a.navigation" that had to be "#faq a" for my use; (3) change var fromTop = 250 to a ternary based on window.innerWidth for differences in mobile vs. desktop; (4) change 400 in the animate to 1, as the animation is not desired and 0 does not work; (5) add if ($('my-page-selector').length before the call to offSetScrollFromLocation in the anonymous function to prevent unnecessary calls on pages where not needed.

Answer (score 1):

Implemented using `:before` worked great until we realized that the pseudo element was actually covering and blocking pointer events that sat *within* the pseudo element's area. Using something like `pointer-events: none` on the `:before` or even directly on the anchor had no affect.

What we ended up doing was making the anchor's positioning absolute and then adjusting it's position to be the offset/height of the fixed area.

**Offset Anchor without Blocking Pointer Events**

```
.section-marker {

    position: absolute;
    top: -300px;
}
```

The value with this is that we're not blocking any elements that might fall within those 300px. The downside is that grabbing that element's position from Javascript needs to take into account that offset so any logic there had to be adjusted.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I got it to finally go to the proper place when you click on the navigation. I added an event handler for the navigation clicks. Then you can just use "scrollBy" to move up on the offset.

```
var offset = 90;

 $('.navbar li a').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $($(this).attr('href'))[0].scrollIntoView();
    scrollBy(0, -offset);
 });
```

Comment: Solves the problem, but not the "without the help of Javascript" part...

Answer (score 1):

I created a div with a few line breaks and gave that the id, I then put the code I wanted to show underneath. The link would then take you to the space above the image and the header would no longer be in the way:

```
<a href="#image">Image</a>
<div id="image"><br><br></div>
<img src="Image.png">
```

Of course, you can change the number of line breaks to suit your needs.
This worked perfectly for me, not sure if there are any problems though, I am still learning HTML.

Comment: Pragmatic, but there is a downside - it only works for the first heading on a page. If there are more headings, you will start to see large gaps in the text because of the `<br>` tags before each heading.

Answer (score 1):

Used this script

```
$(document).on('click', 'a[href^="#"]', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $($.attr(this, 'href')).offset().top -140
    }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: Please try to explain why you think this script would solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

I think this approach is more useful:

`<h2 id="bar" title="Bar">Bar</h2>`

```
[id]:target {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top: -120px;
    visibility: hidden;
}

[id]:target::before {
    content: attr(title);
    top: 120px;
    position: relative;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple and easy way by adding `scroll-padding-top` property to solve this problem, just add this code into your CSS file and see the magic.

for dynamic height and gap variables

```
html {   
    --headerHeight:79px;   
    --gap:40px;   
    scroll-padding-top: calc(var(--headerHeight) + var(--gap)); 
}
```

for fixed gap value

```
html { 
    scroll-padding-top: 120px; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a class with a "paddingtop" so it works ;)

```
<h1><a class="paddingtop">Bar</a></h1>
```

And for css you have:

```
.paddingtop { 
   padding-top: 90px; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this method because for some reason, none of the other solutions proposed actually worked for me. I promise I tried.

```
section {
   position: relative;
   border-top: 52px solid transparent; /* navbar height +2 */
   margin: -30px 0 0;
   -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
   -moz-background-clip: padding;
   background-clip: padding-box;
}

section:before {
   content: "";
   position: absolute;
   top: -2px;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   border-top: 2px solid transparent;
}
```

Replace *section* by a class if you prefer.

source: [Jump links and viewport positioning](http://nicolasgallagher.com/jump-links-and-viewport-positioning/)

- Tested on Firefox 45 and Chrome 52.
- bootstrap version: 3.3.7

For those who do not believe me I kindly prepared a jsfiddle with the solution in it: [SOLUTION](http://jsfiddle.net/eLqqx1u8/)

Answer (score 0):

CSS trick will be a workaround. A proper solution which will work in all scenario can be implemented using jQuery.

Refer to https://codepen.io/pikeshmn/pen/mMxEdZ

**Approach:** We get the height of fixed nav using *document.getElementById('header').offsetHeight*
And offset the scroll to this value.

```
var jump=function(e){  

e.preventDefault();                        //prevent "hard" jump
  var target = $(this).attr("href");       //get the target

      //perform animated scrolling
      $('html,body').animate(
        {
          scrollTop: $(target).offset().top - document.getElementById('header').offsetHeight - 5  //get top-position of target-element and set it as scroll target
        },1000,function()                  //scrolldelay: 1 seconds
        {
          location.hash = target;          //attach the hash (#jumptarget) to the pageurl
        });
      }

  $(document).ready(function()
  {
    $('a[href*="#"]').bind("click", jump); //get all hrefs
    return false;
  });
```

P.S:

- It includes a nice 5 pixels difference between header and target
- Scroll effect is not hard, rather smooth; Smooth Scrolling

Comment: OP asked not to use javascript.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple CSS only answer is to put this at the top of your stylesheet:

```
a{padding-top: 90px;}
a:link{padding-top: unset;}
```

The first style regulates all anchor tags where the second styles anchor tags with a hyperlink.

*Note: This currently works in Firefox and Edge but nor in Chrome.*

Answer (score -1):

The top answer here created a 60px-high  tag that was masking other links that stopped working as a result. I found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13184714/2771889) working without side-effects.

```
<a class="anchor" id="top"></a>

a.anchor {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top: -60px;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```