# Anchor being covered by fixed Menu

Tags: css, menu, anchor, fixed

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [HTML position:fixed page header and in-page anchors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4086107/html-positionfixed-page-header-and-in-page-anchors)
>   [Scroll to anchor with fixed header, content hidden behind header, margin and top padding not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4835885/scroll-to-anchor-with-fixed-header-content-hidden-behind-header-margin-and-top)

I am looking for some help please.  I am building a site with a fixed menu at the top.  I have a section in the site where people can click on a year, and the page will scroll to that section (I am using anchors) Here is the problem. when you click on a year, the page scrolls down to the right place but the year is covered by the menu.  Is there a way to push the anchor down by about 45px/50px so that the menu is not cover the year?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scroll to anchor with fixed header, content hidden behind header, margin and top padding not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4835885/scroll-to-anchor-with-fixed-header-content-hidden-behind-header-margin-and-top) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4086107/html-positionfixed-page-header-and-in-page-anchors

Answer (score 0):

You could place the anchor higher up, maybe somewhere near the bottom of the previous section so that the year shows up.

Comment: Hi there Michelle.

Thank you for your answer, I did think of that one, even changing the years in the Anchor so that the Year would show up in the right place, but when the client get there hands on it anything could happen. I need to put some height in somehow to push the year down by 45/50px