# {text-indent : -9999} for image replace not working

Tags: html, css

Any ideas why?

http://jsfiddle.net/FHUb2/

```css
.dashboard-edit,
.dashboard-delete {
  height: 30px;
  width: 50px;
  background: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRZeB.png") no-repeat top left;
  text-indent: -9999px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" title="Edit" class="dashboard-edit">Edit</a>
<a href="#" title="Delete" class="dashboard-delete">Delete</a>
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

`text-indent` does not work on inline elements and `<a>` is an inline element so you can define `display:block` or `display:inline-block` to your `<a>` tag.

```css
.dashboard-edit,
.dashboard-delete {
  height: 30px;
  width: 50px;
  background: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRZeB.png") no-repeat top left;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" title="Edit" class="dashboard-edit">Edit</a>
<a href="#" title="Delete" class="dashboard-delete">Delete</a>
```

Comment: display block did fix the issue for me. Thanks.

Comment: I had to use display block and remove float property.

Answer (score 67):

Apart from the reason that `text-indent` doesn't works on inline elements. another reason is if your element or one of its parent has been set with `text-align:right`

So make sure your element has been set with `text-align:left` to fix this.

Comment: thanks this was the case with me.. so whats is the work around for this?

Comment: Brilliant tip. text-align:left

Comment: I've had this issue in the past and never understood why. Applying `text-align: left;` overrides a `text-align: right` declaration for a parent element and fixes the problem. Yay!

Comment: i get stuck scratching my head on this like once a year and always find my way back here. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

`<a/>` tags are not 'blocks'

add the following:

```
display: inline-block;
```

Answer (score 5):

In my case text indent was not working on H1 because of :before pseudo tag I used to correct a [fixed header positioning problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4086107/html-positionfixed-page-header-and-in-page-anchors)

```
.textpane h1:before, .textpane h2:before, .textpane h3:before {
  display:block;
  content:"";
  height:90px;
  margin:-90px 0 0;
}
```

This applied to H1 elements with negative indent hack showed text on top of the images in FF &  Opera

Comment: Nice! In my case I was able to switch to `:after` and it made no difference, and now text-indent works!

Comment: +1 For switching :before to :after. I'd have never really though there was a difference.

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind that (if you care) with inline-block the text-indent image replacement technique will fail in IE7. I recently had a heck of a time figuring that one out. I used this technique for IE7 and it works:

```
.ir {
    font: 0/0 a;
    text-shadow: none;
    color: transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue, I checked display and text-align. finally I find out.

I was working on rtl design and in the theme the direction changed to rtl.

You can change the container or each element to ltr to fix the issue.

```
dashboard-edit, .dashboard-delete { 
    direction: ltr;
}
```