# Why text indent in <a> works only with display:block?

Tags: css

Why text indent in `<a>` works only with display:block? When I leave it inline, text indentation doesn't work

Comment: Um, because that's what the spec says it should do? http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/text.html#indentation-prop

Comment: Certain CSS properties don't work with inline elements. `<a>` is an inline element. When you set to block, it's not inline anymore

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7723468/text-indent-9999-for-image-replace-not-working

Comment: @j08691 you crack me up. just as sarcastic as I am haha

Answer (score 2):

`text-indent` only works on block level elements, not on inline elements.

Instead use `display: inline-block` or `padding-left` on the anchor.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/jwscmnj3/)