# Web fixed page header and in-page anchors went wrong position

Tags: html, css, position, anchor

I have a trouble in web fixed page header and in-page anchors. First I see this post:
["HTML position:fixed page header and in-page anchors"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4086107/html-positionfixed-page-header-and-in-page-anchors)
, then I type the code below:

HTML:

```
<a href="category.html#phone">PHONE</a>
<div class="subject2">PHONE</div>
<a name="phone" class="anchor"></a>
```

CSS:

```
.anchor{
    position:relative;
    top:-166px;
}
```

[SEE ON jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ajjEE/)

This works on Chrome and Firefox in office computer, but the strange thing happen when I see on my own computer: the anchor shows top:0 instead of top:-166, just like IE!
What's wrong when it show different in same browser? What did I miss?
Thank you! :)

Comment: When asking a question like this, it is helpful to add a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or the like.

Comment: "top" is typically used with elements that are positioned absolutely, and this can lead to unpredictable behavior when used with relatively positioned elements.

Comment: Please don't use the "fix" tag unless your question is about FIX protocol.