# Anchor links to wrong place

Tags: html, hyperlink, anchor

I am having a problem with what seems like it should have a simple solution.
I have anchor links set up in a html page and am having a problem with one of the links.

Here is the code I am using...

```
<div class="top-menu">
<a href="#about">About</a></br>
<a href="#jersey">Jersey</a></br>
<a href="#social">SocialMedia</a></br>
<a href="#art">Art</a></br>
</div>
```

*The links*

```
<a id="about"></a>
<a id="jersey"></a>
<a id="social"></a>
<a id="art"></a>
```

*The anchors*

The problem I am having is that 'About','Jersey' and 'Art' work perfectly fine, but 'social' keeps linking to 'jersey'.

I am using nice scroll, and a scroll to anchor script, however I have removed these and get the same effect.

As said previously I have also tried linking with name="" and id="".

The anchors were not inside a div, but I have tried that also.

EDIT: Also just tried using div tags instead of a.

Comment: Can you try using this?
This helped me to fix my issue.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4086107/fixed-page-header-overlaps-in-page-anchors

Answer (score 0):

It means you have multiple element having same Id also there is another possibility that Id is in scroll limit

Comment: Thankyou,I have searched for the same id and this is not the case. It is not linking to a random location, it is linking to #jersey instead of #social

Comment: I have also just tried giving it a new obscure id and updated the link. No luck. The same thing happens.

Answer (score 0):

I am still unsure as to this problem however I have found a solution. I have placed the anchor inside the div below it.