# Sticky/Fixed Header with Anchor Tags - Other solutions found not working

Tags: html, css, anchor

The problem I have is the same as the link below where a sticky header is present and clicking on the anchor tags causes the anchor to put whatever I had anchored right behind the sticky header. I'm looking for a non-JS solution to this problem.

I looked at: 
[offsetting an html anchor to adjust for fixed header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10732690/offsetting-an-html-anchor-to-adjust-for-fixed-header).

and

[HTML position:fixed page header and in-page anchors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4086107/html-positionfixed-page-header-and-in-page-anchors)

So in my the html I had:

```
<a href="#first"> </a>
```

And the anchor tag as follows:

```
<a class="anchor" id="first"> </a>
```

Then in the style sheet I have:

```
.anchor { display: block; position: relative; top: -100px;}
```

That didn't work (as in the header kept blocking the anchor). So I tried:

```
a.anchor{ display: block; position: relative; top: -100px; visibility: hidden;}
```

copied verbatim from the first link.

That also didn't work so I tried:

```
.anchor{
    padding-top: 100px;
    margin-top: -100px;
 }
```

Other attempts:

```
.anchor {
   display: block;    
   position: relative;     
   top: -100px;
   visibility: hidden;
 }

 a.anchor {
    padding-top:600000px;
    height:0px;
 }
```

Suffice to say, this did nothing either.

I tried changing the `<a>` tags to `<spans>` and `<divs>`.
I tried adding text inside the `<a>` tags because I read somewhere that some browsers don't support empty anchor tags.

I'm currently using Chrome, and have tested on Safari as well. I have tried clearing the cache in case that was the issue.

Apparently, one of my CSS rules: display:table-header-group; conflicted with the padding rules. Now I can't display tables but I can get it to pad to the correct location.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Apparently the issue was conflicting CSS rules within my style sheet. As for why (the anchor link didn't even encapsulate the tables that the rules were referring to so I don't know) but changing the rules to the tables fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You may use a non-breaking space:

```
<a class="anchor" id="first">&nbsp;</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

I extended [this method](http://nicolasgallagher.com/jump-links-and-viewport-positioning/#more-robust-method) with the `:target` pseudo element, which is pretty handy.

```
:target {
  margin-top: -30px;
  border-top: 60px solid transparent;
  background-clip: padding-box;
}
```

You can then set the `margin-top` and the `border-top` accordingly to the height of your sticky header.

Answer (score 0):

IF I'm understanding your problem, other than adding padding to #first you probably will not accomplish this without JS.  SO add padding-top to the #first element so that it scrolls to a stop before the heading covers things up.

Hard to illustrate this but basically your page will stop scrolling immediately when the top of the #first element meets the top of the page, so pushing the content inside the #first element down will bring it below the sticky header.

Comment: Hello, I tried adding the padding to the anchor class as shown above. `.anchor { padding-top:100px; }`. However, this padding doesn't do anything to the anchor when I click the anchor link.

Comment: Eh then you may not have understood ... here is what you need: `#first { padding-top: 100px; }` push the #first element down .. not the .anchor.