# How to Avoid Scroll on Hashed A Tag Click with Fixed Height Content

Tags: html, css, css-position, anchor, fragment-identifier

I am currently encountering a tricky issue with hashed anchor links. 
Here is a simple representation of my HTML code :

```
<div class="main-wrap">
<header></header>

<aside>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#article1">Article1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#article2">Article2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#article3">Article3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</aside>

<section>
    <article id="article1">Content Here</article>
    <article id="article2">Content Here</article>
    <article id="article3">Content Here</article>
</section>

<footer></footer>
```

and the CSS :

```
body{overflow: scroll;}

.main-wrap{
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

header{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 3;
    height: 10vh;
}

aside{
    position: fixed;
    width: 22%;
    height: 84vh; /* Equal to 100vh - (header + footer)vh */
    top: 10vh;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 6vh;
}

section{
    position: relative;
    min-height: 84vh; /* Equal to 100vh - (header + footer)vh */
    width: 78%;
    left: 22%; /* Equal to aside width*/
}

footer{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 3;
    height: 6vh;
}
```

I've created a sidebar menu with hashed links to have a scrolled navigation, wich as far as I've been is working. But when I'm clicking on the hashed anchors, all the elements are moving a little further top, **including header and footer** and are hidden by the `overflow:hidden;` property of the `.main-wrap` element. In addition when I go back to the non-hashed page, the issue is still running unless I reload it.

I can't find any clue of how I can fix it. Any ideas ?

**Edited :** I also use a reset.css that is setting the `body` and `html` padding and margin to 0.

**Edited 2 :**
I think I know what's going on. By clicking on an anchor-link the body is forced to scroll the `.main-wrap` div and that's why everything looks like it has moved top. In fact the `overflow:hidden;` property of `.main-wrap` has just moved a little further down and is hiding the wrong parts.

Comment: Similar to this issue w/a fixed header & obscured anchors? One option: add a class to the anchors that has a `padding-top` value to push it down a bit. Alternatively, use a `:before` psuedo-element, or JS to change the element's offset. May not be directly applicable to your sidebar issue, but perhaps the right direction: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4086107/html-positionfixed-page-header-and-in-page-anchors ....

Answer (score 0):

**Default Browser Behavior:**

When you click on a named or hashed link, the browser will try to scroll to have the target named link at the top of the view.

This is what is happening with your code too.

**Another browser default:**

Most browsers have default margins and padding greater than `0` for the `HTML` elements, including the `html` and `body` elements.

Your calculation of `height: 84vh; /* Equal to 100vh - (header + footer)vh */` will cause the content height to be more than the viewport height if the `html` and the `body` tags have margins or paddings greater than `0` (and make it scrollable since you have `body {overflow: scroll;}`).

**Solution:**

Use a `css` reset, or in your case simply add this to your `css`

```
html,
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

**Demo** https://jsfiddle.net/vkrhnf75/1/

Comment: Ups, sorry i forgot to mention that I already use a reset.css with margins and paddings set at 0. It can't come from here.

Comment: If you remove the margin and padding from the demo you will get the scroll. So probably your posted code snippet is not complete or your css reset doesn't reset the margin and padding on html and body.

Comment: Ok, I'm checking it just in case. Look at the 2nd edit I made, I think that's the root of my issue. What do you think ?

Comment: :) your second edit is basically what I'm explaining in my answer.

Comment: I checked the CSS applied to my body and html and couldn't find any value that could be responsible of my issue. This is such a trick -_-

Comment: I found the answer ! It was a meany line-height taller than my footer height (the parent of this disturbing child). 

Thanks for your attention anyway ;)