# jQuery scrollTo: getting links to scroll to underneath the fixed nav

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, scrollto

I've got a fixed nav (for desktop) for this upcoming site (http://rvwinvesting.com/2016/) but right now on desktop, the links in the navbar and forcing the div's to scroll to the very top of the page. So a portion of it appears cut off.

I'd like it to scroll directly underneath the nav so you can see the start of the content of the div. Not sure how to implement that because if I just let's say top+100, it would then scroll to the top of the screen +100 pixels on all screens and I just need it for desktop/laptop. Here's what I'm currently using to make the effect work:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.nav-menu a[href^="#"]' ).click(function(){
        jQuery.scrollTo( this.hash, 1000, { easing:'swing' });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4086107/html-positionfixed-page-header-and-in-page-anchors

Comment: If you play around a little with $(window) and $(document) you can use them to determine the size of the window and document, then use that to determine when/how much to scroll.