# Show HTML bookmark link with space from top of the page

Tags: html, css

First of all, I'm struggling how to title my question. I know it can be better.

So In my simple HTML page, I have 3 bookmarks which I link them by `<a>` tags:

```
<a href="#section1">HTML5</a>
```

I have a fixed *header* at the top of the page and I've set `margin-top` to the sections, so that they appear under the header.

```
header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
}
section {
    padding: 20px;
    margin-right: 200px;
    margin-top: 200px;
}
```

Now the problem is, when I clicke on the bookmark links, HTML tries to scroll to them and show them at the top of the page, which then will be masked by the header.

My question is, is there any way to tell the `<a>` tag to show the bookmark using some margins, so that it appears under the header?

[JSFiddle sample](https://jsfiddle.net/3whqjgj3/)

Comment: @Ardian yes you are right. I was able to fix it by applying `padding-top: 220px`. jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/yxsq3uk1/ voting to close as duplicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9618795/2263683), I fixed the issue

> /* add class="jumptarget" to all targets. */

I changed the answer in my favor and it solved the problem like a charm.

```
.jumptarget::before {
  content:"";
  display:block;
  height:220px; /* fixed header height*/
  margin:-50px 0 0; /* negative fixed header height */
}
```