# Setting anchor link target to be in the view

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have header html element which is positioned fixed at `top: 0` and set `height:120px;`

I have added `margin-top: 120px` to teaser.

I have menu with link to items in the same page. I have a problem in getting those link location to be in the exact view when user clicks on the link.

Half of the link location is hidden under the header and another half is visible to the user which does not look at all.

the structure of the document looks like this;

```
<header>
  <div class="logoContainer">
  </div>
  <div class="navMenu">
    <a href="#featureList">Features</a>
    <a href="#team">Features</a>
  </div>
</header>
<div class="teaser" id="teaserID">
</div>
<div class="features" id="featureList">
</div>
<div id="team">
</div>
```

Comment: Can we get you to post your CSS? And maybe a screenshot of the issue?

Comment: Have you tried offsetting the header height by adding `margin-top: 120px` to your menu element?

Comment: Just for demo purpose, I have used link. Anyways, I have changed it.

Comment: @joh04667 added codepen url

Comment: Please note that [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9618795/854246) may be working in FF now.  I tried it out and it seems to perform similarly to chrome and other browsers.  Also, [using `:target`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28824157/854246) is pretty neat and [fairly well supported now](http://caniuse.com/#search=%3Atarget).