# Why alignment mark list is different on WebKit when using :before height?

Tags: html, css, list, google-chrome, webkit

Code: http://jsbin.com/maropaxivo/1/edit?html,css,output

See the sample code Firefox and Chrome browsers. Why alignment mark list is different?

[image]

```css
li:before {
  height: 20px;
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <ol>
    <li>123</li>
    <li>123</li>
    <li>123</li>
    <li>123</li>
    <li>123</li>
  </ol>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I investigated more into this issue:

1. Here is how it behaves now- note that the `before` is a `block` element while the content of `li` is `inline`.

```css
li:before {
  height: 20px;
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <ol>
    <li>123</li>
    <li>123</li>
    <li>123</li>
    <li>123</li>
    <li>123</li>
  </ol>
</body>
```

2. If I make both the items a block element by wrapping the text in a `div`, we have the same behaviour.

```css
li:before {
  height: 20px;
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <ol>
    <li>
      <div>123</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>123</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>123</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>123</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>123</div>
    </li>
  </ol>
</body>
```

3. If I change the `before` element to `inline-block`, we will finally see the same behavior in Firefox and Chrome:

```css
li:before {
  height: 20px;
  content: " ";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <ol>
    <li>123</li>
    <li>123</li>
    <li>123</li>
    <li>123</li>
    <li>123</li>
  </ol>
</body>
```

4. If I change the `before` element to `inline-block`, and keep the content as `block` we will again see the same behavior in Firefox and Chrome:

```css
li:before {
  height: 20px;
  content: " ";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <ol>
    <li>
      <div>123</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>123</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>123</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>123</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>123</div>
    </li>
  </ol>
</body>
```

**Comments**:

So whenever the `before` is `inline-block` (cases 3 and 4 above) or even `inline` for that matter, we see same behavior in Firefox and Chrome.

1. In Firefox, the numbers are aligned with the first inline element.
2. In Chrome, it doesn't matter even if it is a block element.

I strongly believe that this behavior is because there is a small difference in the user agent(browser) implementation of `list-item` display.

**Conclusion**:

Use `inline-block` and you won't face this discrepancy.

Let me know your feedback on this. Thanks!

**EDIT**:

So if you want it to look like the Firefox implementation of your code in both browsers, you can make the `before` absolute `relative` to the `li`:

```css
li{
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 25px;
}
li:before {
  height: 20px;
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ccc;
  position:absolute;
  top: -20px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <ol>
    <li>123</li>
    <li>123</li>
    <li>123</li>
    <li>123</li>
    <li>123</li>
  </ol>
</body>
```

Comment: I think it's more true that Firefox uses. Can we set like Firefox uses for both browsers?

Comment: see updated answer above... let me know your thoughts on that... Thanks!