# Inconsistency for displaying <li><img /></li>

Tags: html, css, image, google-chrome, firefox

I have a problem with very simple HTML markup, which is rendered different in Chrome and Firefox. I'm wondering whether it is a bug in one of them.

The code is as simple as:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <img />
    </li>
</ul>
```

The problem is that in Chrome the `<li />` element has some padding at the top, but only if its content is an image. There is no problem with e.g. text.

Example fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8c4rujvu/1/

```css
img {
  display: block;
  width: 500px;
}
li {
  border: 1px solid #f00;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg">
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg">
  </li>
  <li>Some text</li>
</ul>
```

This is how it displays in Firefox (50.0.2):
[image: Firefox (50.0.2)]

And in Chrome (55.0.2883.75 m):
[image: Chrome (55.0.2883.75 m)]

What seems to be a problem here?

Comment: adding list-style:none will fix the issue on both

Comment: Isn't that a hack, like we used to do for old good IE 6? :) The question is **why** it is like that.

Comment: You are required to show the complete, minimal markup that shows the problem here, not a jsfiddle which can change or disappear tomorrow.

Comment: @Rob added the code as a snippet too :)

Answer (score 10):

This is due the default browser / user agent styling difference for `display: list-item`.

As a *fix*, you can use `inline-block` and `vertical-align:top` (or even just `vertical-align: top`) for the `img` to get common behaviour - see demo below:

```css
img {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 500px;
}
li {
  border: 1px solid #f00;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg">
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg">
  </li>
  <li>
    Some text
  </li>
</ul>
```

*A related question you may want to look at*: [`Why alignment mark list is different on WebKit when using :before height?`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39547773/why-alignment-mark-list-is-different-on-webkit-when-using-before-height/39548920#39548920)

**Why this happens?**

Given that other browsers do not agree with chrome on this, this clearly looks like a bug and it *is*. See this open bug documented in *Chromium Bug Tracker*:

[***`Table inside list item rendered at wrong position`***](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=332198)(*Example URL*: http://jsfiddle.net/P8Ua7/)

See excerpts from one of the comments in the bug:

> Not limited to tables. Putting a flexbox inside a list-item gives the
>   same result. It also happens if you have replaced content displayed as
>   block.

The OP has an image (which is an inline replaced element) displayed as block!

Here is [`another bug you may want to check out`](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=490273).

Comment: `display: inline-block` generates gap at the bottom, that's why I would like to use `display: block`, especially if the `<img />` is going to be wrapped by `<a />`

Comment: @KrzysztofSowa the *gap* at the bottom will be handled by `vertical-align` property...

Comment: Thanks for your effort, I appreciate it. 
To not repeat myself, please take a look into my other comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41011876/chrome-firefox-inconsistency-for-displaying-liimg-li/41012091?noredirect=1#comment69233686_41012618

Comment: thanks, the reason is the difference in the `list-item` implementation by Firefox and say Chrome - you might want to look [at this question too](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39547773/why-alignment-mark-list-is-different-on-webkit-when-using-before-height/39548920#39548920)...

Answer (score 3):

This issue can simply fix `float:left` property too , check this fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/9wp619xz/

*check with the bug details Fixing Google Chrome compatibility bugs in websites - FAQ*

https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromecompatfaq

```css
img {
  float:left;
  width: 500px;
}
li {
  border: 1px solid #f00;
  float:left;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg">
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg">
  </li>
  <li>Some text</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

It is usually due to browsers default styling. In order to fix this issue, i recommend using a normalize css stylesheet or by adding your own css for the element.

Comment: Which normalization CSS stylesheet would you recomment? I'm already using one, but looks like it doesn't work for such cases.

Comment: This seems to have nothing to do with browser defaults. I do not think that normalizing will help.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is two-fold.

1. Setting the image to `display: inline` solves the empty line above the image. This empty line is a [nasty bug in Chrome](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=332198). This bug makes it effectively impossible to use/start with a non-inline element in a default list item. **A very big deal if you ask me.**
2. Adding `vertical-align: top` places the list marker on the top (which is where you probably want it to go). This also removes the unwanted space below the inline image. The list marker placement and the white space below the inline element are not bugs. This is expected behaviour.

This would result into the following (simple) work-around for the OP:

```
img {
  width: 500px;
  vertical-align: top;
  /* display: inline; *//* This is default, thus can be omitted */
}
li {
  border: 1px solid #f00;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8c4rujvu/3/

Comment: That's exactly what I'm writing about. `display: inline` generates smaller gap at the bottom. `line-height` in such case looks like old good hack for IE 6 ;)

Comment: There is no extra gap if you use `vertical-align: top`.

Comment: True, but it's still some kind of hack, isn't it? I could use other solutions, like `display: block` for `<li />` or `list-style: none` for `<ul />`, but this wouldn't answer the main question - **why** this is like that?

Comment: It is not a hack. Images are default rendered with `vertical align: bottom`. This means the list bullet will show on the bottom of the image (instead of on top). This is being prevented with `vertical-align: top`. As an unexpected bonus this bug does not occur. Adding `display: block` or `line-height: 0` to the <li>-items, however, ARE hacks.

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by the two different approaches these two browsers take while rendering a UL / LI element. I think that is clear from the start :)

*The issue here is not how inline elements behave!*

***The issue here is how list-style properties behave in these two browsers!***

---

If you notice that, the size of gap is *18px*, which is default line height in chrome! If you increase the `font-size` for the `li` then size of dot marker will also increase so as the distance of image from top edge of div.

If Firefox, that dot marker, or `list-style-type` component act as the absolute positioned element, thus any element after simply begin from the `li` *top-left* edge as expected.

But in Chrome, that dot marker, or `list-style-type` component act as the inline element, and like any other inline element will allow an inline/floating element to get in same line as itself. Thus text which is inline by nature began next to the dot! This applies also for image, button, link, span or any such elements!

Now what you feel as an issue is perfectly normal behaviour for those elements. Even If two elements are floating or inline, if they can not get in horizontal width of parent, the latter element fall down to next line! Similar is the case with display:block elements as they by default start on a new line!

In your example images have `display:block`, thus they will always begin on new line! But even if you remove that property, still image are quite big to fit in parent, thus it'll fall down & show a gap. (This is for smaller screens only, on larger screen this won't be an issue for inline-block image)

Again, weird part is that, div acts a inline element in this case, even if you give the width above 100%! From this I concluded that, if wrapping of content is possible then that element begin on new line but if content can not wrapped then it starts on a new line!

**Note:**
This is based on my observations & past experience! If anybody have links to official documentation for this case please paste if here. Also any suggestion to improve this answer are welcome.

I've updated your JSFiddle with more examples: https://jsfiddle.net/8c4rujvu/5/

Comment: Thanks for your anwer. @kukkuz found the bug that causes this newline in the Chrome bug tracker. You might want to look into this answer. I think acknowledging that this is an unexpected bug would improve your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for you HTML

```
ul li {
display:block;
}
```

```css
img {
  display: block;
  width: 500px;
}

li {
  border: 1px solid #f00;
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><img src="http://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg"></li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg">
  </li>
  <li>
    Some text
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @kukkuz but maybe it's the simplest solution that needs author

Comment: @iXplo resetting the `display` or resetting `list-style` however do not allow you to use the bullets/numbering, if that is required...

Comment: yep "if that is required". you still can use bg-images or `::before`

Comment: @iXplo that's my point, *resetting* will require you to use psuedo elements and create the bullets/numbers... if the aim is to use the default bullets of `li` then why would you do that?

Comment: `ul` often uses for blocks of same type because it shorter and always have parent (fixed structure). it's more effective in cascading with css

Comment: what do you mean by that?

Comment: Yeah, I know that applying `display: block` helps in this case. However I would rather to not use such hacks - I'm wondering why Chrome displays that gap by default.