# CSS issue with href links to section of text in main - jumps to wrong location on page

Tags: html, css

I'm writing some html and css to create a webpage. On the left of the page is a nav section. At the top is a header, below which is a 'main' section containing text in various sections, and below that is a footer.
I have managed to get the header and footer to remain fixed as desired and also get the main section to scroll between the header and footer. The links in the nav are supposed to let the user jump to a section of main as required. However, when clicking on introduction, the introduction section gets positioned at the very top of the page (hidden under the header) where as I would like it to jump to its position just below the header. I've tried various combinations of setting top and position:absolute in main but without success. Can anybody help?
The html and css are below:

index.html:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
<title>John Doe</title>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="homepage.css">

<style type="text/css">
</style>

</head>
<body>
<header id="top">
    <h1>
        <dl>
            <dt>
                John Doe
            </dt>
            <dd>
                <img src="logo.jpg" alt="Logo" >
            </dd>
        </dl>
    </h1>
</header>

<nav class="navlist">
    <ul class="menuitem">
        <li><a href="#introduction">Introduction</a></li>
        <li><a href="#prevExp">Previous Experience</a></li>
        <li><a href="#skills">Skills</a></li>
        <li><a href="#courses_taken">Courses Taken</a></li>
        <li><a href="#courses_being_taken">Courses Being Taken</a></li>
        <li><a href="#useful_links">Useful Links</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        <img src="selfie.jpg" alt="Selfie" >
    </ul>
</nav>

<div id="main">
<h2><a id="introduction">Introduction</a></h2>
<p>Welcome to my home page! This page tells you a little bit about myself.</p>

<p>Blah blah blah</p>

<h2><a id="prevExp">Previous Experience</a></h2>
<p>I have worked at 
    <a href="http://www.prodrive.com/" target="_BLANK">Prodrive</a>, 
    <a href="http://www.lotuscars.com/engineering"> Lotus Engineering </a>and 
    <a href="http://www.ricardo.com/">Ricardo</a>.
</p>

<p>At Prodrive I did some stuff.</p>

<p>At Lotus I did some stuff.</p>

<p>At Ricardo I did some stuff.</p>

<h2><a id="skills">Skills</a></h2>
<ol>
    <li>Awesomeness</li>
    <li>Mathematics</li>
    <li>Problem Solving</li>
    <li>CSS?</li>
</ol>

<h2><a id="courses_taken">Courses taken</a></h2>
<ul>
    <li>BEng Degree</li>
    <li>Games Programming</li>
    <li>Java</li>
    <li>Android Programming</li>
</ul>

<!-- Created nested list to show current course and its modules -->
<h2><a id="courses_being_taken">Courses being taken</a></h2>
<ul>
<li>MSc Degree
    <ul>
        <li><h3>Modules</h3></li>
        <li>Apps</li>
        <li>Research</li>
        <li>Databases</li>
        <li>Internet</li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>

<h2><a id="useful_links">Useful Links</a></h2>
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_intro.asp" >HTML5 Introduction from w3schools</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<h2><a id="contact">Contact</a></h2>
<ul>
    <li>Address: xxxx</li>
    <li>Telephone: xxxx</li>
    <li>Email: <a href="mailto:xxxx@uea.ac.uk" >xxxx</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<footer>
    <!-- Horizontal rule and update comment -->
    <hr />
    <p>Page last updated 30/09/2016 by Stephen Whiddett</p>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

homepage.css:

```
body {margin:0; padding:0;}

header {border: 0px solid white;}
nav {border: 2px ;}
footer {border: 2px ;}
div#main {border: 2px ;}

h1 {font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; 
    font-size:x-large; 
    color:blue;
    font-style: italic;}

h2 {font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; 
    font-size:medium; 
    color:#0088FF;
    font-style: italic;}

header{ width: 100%;
        height: 12vh;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        background: #AAAAAA;
}

#main {
    left:6em;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 13vh 0 6vh 6em;
}

footer{ position: fixed;
        width:100%;
        height:6vh;
        bottom:0;
        text-align:center;
        background: white;}


p { font-family:Helvetica,Arial; 
    font-size:x-small;}

a {background-color:yellow}

header a {background-color:inherit}

nav img {max-width:100%;}

ul.menuitem {font-size:small; 
            margin:0;
            padding:1em;}

nav.navlist {width:6em;
            position: fixed;
            top:12%;
            bottom:94%;}

header dt {float:left;}
header dd {float:right;}
header dl {padding:1%;}

header dt {
    position: absolute;
    top: 6vh;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

It may be necessary for you to reduce the window size of your browser in order to see the issue I've described to ensure that main cannot fit on the screen all at once.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4086107/html-positionfixed-page-header-and-in-page-anchors

Comment: **It is not a CSS issue**: the browser is navigating to the hash correctly, but the content is partially obstructed because you have positioned a fixed element on top of that—the browser does not take overlying content into question when computing for the scroll distance/viewport positioning. You will either require (1) a top margin/padding on all target elements that is the height of the fixed element, or (2) a JS-based approach that overrides the default viewport positioning calculations.