# Offsetting an html anchor to adjust for fixed header using grid

Tags: html, css, anchor

I am trying to get the right position of an anchor with a fix header but it won't work. I've tried solutions provided at stackoverflow and many other sites. I couldn't make any solution to work properly.

I don't know if the reason is that I am using grid and viewport units.

My goal is to understand how to make it work just using Html and css only, and why I haven't been able to make it work following the solutions given.

You can see the html and css:

https://codepen.io/sevaro/pen/GPLeyE

```
    /* css*/ 
    #container {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 1fr;
        grid-template-rows: 8vh 92vh 92vh 92vh;
        grid-template-areas: 
            "m"
            "a"
            "w"
            "c";
        }
    nav {
        grid-area: m;
        background-color: grey;
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: row;
        justify-content: flex-end;
        align-items: center;
        position: -webkit-sticky;
        position: sticky;
        top: 0;
    }    
    .about {
        grid-area: a;
        background-color: blue;
        padding-right: 10px;
    }
    .work {
        grid-area: w;
        background-color: green;
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: row wrap;
        justify-content: space-evenly;
        align-items: center;
    }
    .contact {
        grid-area: c;
        background-color: yellow;
    }
/* html */
    <div id="container">

        <nav>
            <div class="ab"><a href="#whoami">About</a></div>
            <div class="wo"><a href="#whativedone">Work</a></div>
            <div class="co"><a href="#contactme">Contact</a></div>
        </nav>


        <article class="about" id="whoami">
        </article>

        <article class="work" id="whativedone">
            <div class="project">
                <img height="50px" width="50px" alt="Project 1">
                <p>Project 1</p>
            </div>            
            <div class="project">
                <img height="50px" width="50px" alt="Project 2">
                <p>Project 2</p>
            </div>            
            <div class="project">
                <img height="50px" width="50px" alt="Project 3">
                <p>Project 3</p>
            </div>            
            <div class="project">
                <img height="50px" width="50px" alt="Project 4">
                <p>Project 4</p>
            </div>            
            <div class="project">
                <img height="50px" width="50px" alt="Project 5">
                <p>Project 5</p>
            </div>            
        </article>

        <article class="contact" id="contactme">
        </article>
```

I really appreciate any help.

Thanks

I've tried these: http://nicolasgallagher.com/jump-links-and-viewport-positioning/demo/

These too: https://www.wikitechy.com/technology/css-offsetting-html-anchor-adjust-fixed-header/

and many others.

Comment: Hey Sergio,  It would defiantly help remove some of your issues if you did not set the grid on your header (nav tag) it will cause the size of your header to fluctuate making it more difficult to account for.  If you have more code (content) it would be helpful for us if you would post that as well.  Thanks and good luck

Comment: I'm not sure what you need to do exactly. Can you please explain?

Comment: @sergio it is no the right.. Can you please tell what exactly you want. thanks

Comment: First, thanks for your replies.

Comment: First, thanks for your replies. I have defined a grid in a div that works as container. Inside the grid, I have defined 4 rows: navigation menu, about section, work section, and a contact section. Inside the nav I have a flexbox to display three divs on the right side (three links). Each link inside the nav has an anchor to a section inside the document. The problem is that the section displayed is misplaced. I have tried many solutions but none of them worked. I hope this explanation is more clear. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fixed page header overlaps in-page anchors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4086107/fixed-page-header-overlaps-in-page-anchors)

Answer (score 15):

Try using [scroll-margin-top](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-margin-top), it's [pretty widely adopted](https://caniuse.com/#search=scroll-margin-top).

Simply add the following CSS to the element you want to scroll to:

```
.element {
  scroll-margin-top: 2em;
}
```

Comment: Note that `scroll-margin` will not inherit so you CANNOT just set it once like `html { scroll-margin-top: 10vh; }`. However, `:target { scroll-margin-top: 10vh; }` should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is what worked for me: 
**CSS**

```
h2{
    position:relative;
}
h2 > a{
    position:absolute;
    top: -12.5vh;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<nav>
    <div><a href="#whoami">About</a></div> <!––Link-->
</nav>

<article>
     <h2><a id="whoami"></a>ABOUT</h2> <!––Anchor-->
</article>
```

Hope this helps someone in the future. 
Thanks