# Bootstrap fixed position navbar header and anchor tags in Internet Explorer and Edge browsers

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

Moderators: 
Please do not mark this question as duplicate as the other solutions do not solve the problem for Internet Explorer and Edge browsers.

With a Bootstrap navbar header with fixed positioning, anchor tags are covered by the header in Internet Explorer and Edge browsers.

Looking for a way to offset anchor from the height of the header.

Proposed popular solutions in Stack Overflow do not have solutions for Internet Explorer and Edge browsers.

Preference is for HTML or CSS.

The following popular solutions do not work in Internet Explorer and Edge browsers.  In fact, the browser does not even jump to the anchor with these solutions.

```
a.anchor {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top: -250px;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Source: [offsetting an html anchor to adjust for fixed header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10732690/offsetting-an-html-anchor-to-adjust-for-fixed-header)

```
*[id]:before { 
  display: block; 
  content: " "; 
  margin-top: -75px; 
  height: 75px; 
  visibility: hidden; 
}
```

Source: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/1768#issuecomment-46519033 or [Fixed page header overlaps in-page anchors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4086107/fixed-page-header-overlaps-in-page-anchors)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use F12 developer tools to check the html and css style, make sure you have attached the css style, and the related css style is not overridden (if the css style is overridden, you could use "!important" ).

The following code works well on my side (using IE 11 and Edge browser), you could refer to it:

```
<head>
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        a.anchor {
            display: block;
            position: relative;
            top: 10px;            
            }
    </style>
</head>
<body style="height:1500px">

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
            </div>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a class="anchor" href="#">Page 1</a></li>
                <li><a class="anchor" href="#">Page 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container" style="margin-top:50px">
        <h3>Fixed Navbar</h3>
   </div>
</body>
```

The output like this:

[image]

Comment: Thx for the answer, but I was not asking about the navbar links.  I am asking about in-page anchor tags that I link to.  Those links are covered by the navbar when I "jump" to them.  See two source links in original question for more examples/clarification.