# IE11: Add extra space above anchor tags

Tags: css, internet-explorer-11

I read many suggestions how to add an extra space above anchor tags, but none of them is working in IE11.

I need 250 px space above them because my sticky header is ca 250 px high.

I tried two most promising looking methods, one with the `target` element, ant the second one with the `id` elements:

```
/* target-Method: Working in Chrome, but not working in IE 11 */

:target::before {
  content:"";
  display:inline-block;
  height:250px; 
  margin:-250px 0 0 0; 
}
```

```
/* id+before - Method: Working in Chrome, but not working in IE 11 */

h2[id], h3[id] { 
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
h2[id]::before, h3[id]::before { 
  display: inline-block !important; 
  content: ' ' !important;
  height: 250px !important;
  margin-top: -250px !important;
  visibility: hidden !important;
  pointer-events: none !important;
  position: absolute; 
  z-index: -1; 
}
```

But none of them is working in IE11.

**Or are overlapping the link in the element above!**

Codepen (here without a sticky header): 
https://codepen.io/abc001/pen/oRmmwp

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4086107/fixed-page-header-overlaps-in-page-anchors

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the following code with your Html elements:

```
<style>
    /* target-Method: Working in Chrome, but not working in IE 11 */
    :target::before {
        content: "" !important;
        display: inline-block !important;
        background-color: antiquewhite !important;
        height: 250px !important;
        width: 100% !important;
        margin-top:250px;
    }

    /* id+before - Method: Working in Chrome, but not working in IE 11 */
    h2[id], h3[id] {
        position: relative;
        z-index: 1;
    }

        h2[id]::before, h3[id]::before {
            content: ' RR this -';
        }

    /* Spacer */
    .spacer {
        width: 100%;
        height: 500px;
    }

    .row .col-12{
        background-color:aquamarine
    }
</style>
```

The result as below:

[image]