# All popular solutions for offsetting anchors for fixed header disable my links/buttons

Tags: css

I found a ton of articles how to fix the offsets for anchors if you have a fixed header. Most of them are similar to this

```
.anchorclass:before {
content: "";
display:block;
height: 204px; 
margin: -204px 0 0;
visibility: hidden;
```

}

All variants I found work for the problem. But they all seem to somehow overlay over the 204 pixel before the anchor, which render all the links and buttons in this area unclickable.
So link, followed by anchor within 204 pixel -> cannot click.

I tried to fix this with z-index: 0 which does not work either. I could not find a solution for this, not even somebody having the same issue

Edit:

I thought this is very common sorry. Base problem is that if you have any fixed header and jump to an anchor on the page, the anchor is hidden behind the header, ie jumping to anchor counts from top, not from the fixed header.

Here are links that explain the problem in detail, there are thousands of results googling "offset anchor fixed header" describing problem and solution above

[Fixed page header overlaps in-page anchors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4086107/fixed-page-header-overlaps-in-page-anchors)

https://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2017/10/23/css-tip-fixed-headers-and-section-anchors/

https://timoanttila.com/tutorials/offsetting-anchor-links-with-fixed-header

Solutions are all similar as explained above. But nobody describes the behavior i have, that all links in the offset are rendered unclickable.
I dont know what sample code to add. Any fixed header, any anchor will produce the problem.

Comment: Can you add your HTML markup? The remaining CSS for the header?

Comment: Sorry, i dont saw this as relevant. header is position fixed, top 0, height 204 px. wherever there is an anchor in the long pages, all elements 204 pixel before that are not clickable

Comment: Your description doesnt make sense without seeing the structure. I actually still dont know what you mean by "offsetting anchors".

Comment: I'd have to agree, that class in your example looks like a really unnecessary hack used in place of understanding good 'ol fashioned box model. If you show us what your trouble is with more context I'm betting it's much simpler than you think.

Comment: what do you mean by "I found a ton of articles" I can not find any, if there are so many, why not show at least one example?

Comment: Very sorry, I did not post here often before. I tried to add info for clarity