# How to offset a anchor link to clear fixed header?

Tags: html, css, anchor, offset

As the title describes. I am trying to offset the anchor link, so it appears 100px from the top of the viewport.

This is what I have tried so far.

```
<style>
   :target {
      display: block;
      position: relative;
      top: 100px; 
      visibility: hidden;
      }
 </style>

<a href="#01"> Go to link 01</a> 
  
<h2 id="01"> link 01</h2>
```

edit::
I think I miss read the online tutorial I was following. I have also tried this, but still can't get it to work.

```
<style>
   :target {
      display: block;
      position: relative;
      top: 100px; 
      margin: -100px 0;
      }
 </style>

<a href="#01"> Go to link 01</a> 

<h2 id="01"> link 01</h2>
```

Comment: Why do you have visibility hidden added to the target element? It will not be visible even if your code is working !

Comment: I got this code from an online tutorial. It's weird because the link still shows up.

Comment: Were you able to resolve?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fixed page header overlaps in-page anchors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4086107/fixed-page-header-overlaps-in-page-anchors)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to work.

```
:target:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 100px;
    margin: -100px 0 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The CSS applies on the h2 after you click on the anchor. That is how :target css works.
Your code will hide the element once you click on the anchor. If that is not required then remove it.

Now your problem of making H2 appear below the header.
For this you need to either add position absolute or fixed (depends upon your final HTML), instead of relative.

This is the updated code

```
<style>

   :target{
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      top: 100px; 
      }
 </style>
```