# Customize scrolling menu behavior

Tags: css

I have this application:

https://jsfiddle.net/claudiopb/uovdLg58/1/

with a menu in a fixed header at the top and it's behaving like this below:

[image]

The fixed header moves over the top overlapping part of the div.

I would like it to behave like this below, going to this white part of the margin at the top of the div without overlapping the div.

[image]

How do I do that? If this is impossible, with only CSS, I also accept suggestions with JavaScript. Thanks

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#page-1">Page 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#page-2">Page 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#page-3">Page 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#page-4">Page 4</a></li>

            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <div class="content">
        <div class="inner-div" id="page-1">Page 1</div>
        <div class="inner-div" id="page-2">Page 2</div>
        <div class="inner-div" id="page-3">Page 3</div>
        <div class="inner-div" id="page-4">Page 4</div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

header {
    background-color: gray;
    position: fixed;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin-top:-20px;
}


nav ul li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right:10px;   
}

nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color:black;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
    color: white;
  }

nav ul li a:active {
  color: white;
}


.inner-div {
    font-size:32px;
    display:flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;  
    background-color: green;
    margin: 20px 20px 20px 20px;

}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fixed page header overlaps in-page anchors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4086107/fixed-page-header-overlaps-in-page-anchors)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add some scroll margin to inner div (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-margin)

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

header {
  background-color: gray;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: -20px;
}

nav ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

nav ul li a:active {
  color: white;
}

.inner-div {
  scroll-margin: 120px; /* added */
  font-size: 32px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: green;
  margin: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#page-1">Page 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#page-2">Page 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#page-3">Page 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#page-4">Page 4</a></li>

    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>

<div class="content">
  <div class="inner-div" id="page-1">Page 1</div>
  <div class="inner-div" id="page-2">Page 2</div>
  <div class="inner-div" id="page-3">Page 3</div>
  <div class="inner-div" id="page-4">Page 4</div>
</div>
```