# Fixed navigation bar header that also considers its height

Tags: javascript, html, css

I made a fixed navigation bar header that when I press the buttons it goes to certain point of my page, but it doesn't considers its own height I mean:
[image]
[image]

[image]

I searched, but didn't found the answer, I even tried manually move it in a desesperation attempt:

```js
let buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.navigation a');

let func = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        window.scrollY = window.scrollY + header.offsetHeight
    }, 1000);
}

buttons.forEach((element) => {
    element.addEventListener("click", func)
});
```

but didn't work either, how can I do it?

Comment: Found solutions for this issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10732690/offsetting-an-html-anchor-to-adjust-for-fixed-header) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4086107/fixed-page-header-overlaps-in-page-anchors)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fixed page header overlaps in-page anchors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4086107/fixed-page-header-overlaps-in-page-anchors)

Comment: I don't know why I don't choose the correct words to search, thanks.